How to mention wild characters in karate scenario tags
I've a requirement of executing multiple scenarios with the tags of SL_1, SL_2, SL_3 and so on is it possible to execute SL_*.
I've tried with -Dcucumber options = --tags@SL_* it executed all the scenarios some of the scenarios which doesn't belong to the mentioned tag, for example @dev_*.
Given tag - @SL_*
But executed all tags ......
